whatsapp-web.js@1.23.0 after scan qr Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
After I scan QR successfuly I get this error:
node:internal/process/promises:288
        triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
        ^

Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
    at evaluate (evaluate at Client.initialize (D:\xxxx\Whatsapp\ap
tedWorld.js:124:16)
    at async CdpFrame.evaluate (D:\xxxx\Whatsapp\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\api\Frame.js:343:20)
    at async CdpPage.evaluate (D:\xxxx\Whatsapp\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\api\Page.js:828:20)  
    at async Client.initialize (D:\xxxx\Whatsapp\node_modules\whatsapp-web.js\src\Client.js:323:9)
    at moduleRaid (:14:2)
    at fillModuleArray (:5:73)

I installed the version of whatsapp-web.js@1.23.0, Node.js v18.12.0, and puppeteer@^22.4.1"
